# php function does not returns correct value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have written this function to check for duplicate entries before inserting a record.

```
function checkDuplicate($table, $field, $value){
  global $pdo;
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `$table` WHERE :field = :value");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':field', $field);
  $stmt-> bindValue(':value', $value);
  $stmt-> execute();
  $f = $stmt->fetch();

  if($f['cnt'] > 0){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I call it this way

```
echo checkDuplicate("members", "mem_uname", $uname);
```

However, this always returns 0 even if there exists a similar record. I have rechecked several times but I failed to notice what's wrong with the code.

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for a column name.

Comment: You need to use `where \`$field\` = :value`

Comment: And see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php for how to get a more detailed error message which might have given you a clue.